# How to get the name of the current scalajs / uTest test case

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scala.js, utest

How can I get the name of the currently running uTest test case?

During the test case I usually use println(...) or log.debug(...) to print and check various values.
At the beginning of the test case I print the name of the test case.

I can always do this:

```
object MyTests extends TestSuite

  def tests = TestSuite {

    "MyTest01" - {

      println("MyTest01 starting ***************************************************")

      val x = Thing.doComplexCalc
      println("x = " + x )

      val y = AnotherThing.doSomethingMore( x )
      println("y = " + y )
      assert(y=="mysterious output")
    }
  }
}
```

In this (extremely simplified) example "MyTest01" is duplicated. What I'm looking for is a way to remove the duplication, e.g. like this:

```
object MyTests extends TestSuite

  def tests = TestSuite {

    "MyTest01" - {

      println(getTest().name + " starting ***************************************************")

      val x = Thing.doComplexCalc
      println("x = " + x )

      val y = AnotherThing.doSomethingMore( x )
      println("y = " + y )
      assert(y=="mysterious output")
    }
  }
}
```

Test name is available from tests.toSeq().name but how to know what case is running especially if they are run parallel using sbt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not available right now. There's an open issue to make it so

https://github.com/lihaoyi/utest/issues/71

Comment: It's a good news that it is coming. Any chances to have it in the next release?

Comment: Probably will happen whenever the next release occurs.

Comment: https://github.com/lihaoyi/utest/issues/71 does not answer the question. Following other issues from there and/or PRs for there do not answer the question either. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
import utest._
...
val name = implicitly[utest.framework.TestPath].value
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, explaining *how* it answers the question will ensure that it remains valuable for future visitors.

Comment: @miken32 : The question asks how to obtain the name of a certain test case. The snippet is pretty clear and provides a direct, concise and precise answer to the question. By the way, I even provide the import statement, something people rarely provides.

Comment: @RichardGomes, the code snippet looks fine. But don't assume that code speaks for itself! What is needed is a brief contextual response to the question; describe succinctly what the code example does, in a way that responds to the specifics of the question. It doesn't need to be long; but it does need to be an answer :-)